# Hibernate: Order of access to the different caches

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I am fairly new to hibernate and the caching features which it provides. After some reading I gather that there are essentially four different caches, two of which are not activated by default:

- Hibernate 1st Level Cache
- Hibernate Query Plan Cache
- Hibernate 2nd Level Cache (optional)
- Hibernate Query Cache (optional)

**Can someone explain to me in which order these caches are accessed when a piece of client software triggers a query?** (Assuming now, that we have all four of these caches active and populated).

I'd like to get an understanding in terms of: first Hibernate looks in this cache, then tries this&that, then checks this cache, then ..., eventually still does this&that SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it depends on how you access data.

If you're accessing some entity which needs to be lazily loaded Hibernate would check 1st and 2nd level caches in that order and issue a query on cache misses. Thus 1st and 2nd level caches could also be named entity caches.

The Query Cache on the other hand would store the results of queries that have been executed and would be used if you execute queries yourself. The cache key would be the query and the parameters so you'd get a cache hit if both do match exactly. Even then the entity caches might be involved since the Query Cache would just store the ids of entities and Hibernate would then have to look those up in an entity cache or load them.

The Query Plan Cache is also use when executing queries but would just cache the parsed query (most likely the AST), i.e. the query is still being executed but on a cache hit wouldn't have to be parsed again.

Here's a link with some more information. It's a bit dated but the general concepts should still be valid: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html